# How to distinguish between output of numerous similar commands

Tags: bash, command-line, ls

Say I am issuing `ls -la` in a directory that has hundreds if not thousands of files, then changing to another directions and issuing `ls -la`. I then need to scroll up to see what files are in the most recent directory.

However the issue I am having is mixing up the contents of my first `ls -la` and the second. What I have been doing is just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> about fifty times so there is a sizable gap and I can tell what output belongs to what.

There must be a better way to do this, I have searched but don't really know what terms to search for and am just out of ideas.  I wished `clear` would help but it does not help me in this case.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, just redirect the two outputs to files so you can browse forth and back, or search, or compare, or postprocess in any way you like.

Comment: But this is an issue I run into numerous times when working in the shell and redirecting output to a file, and then `cat file | less` finding what I want and then `rm file` is an even larger pain by my needs.  I do appreciate the idea but was thinking I cannot be the first person to ever come across this issue and there must be a work around.

Comment: pressing enter 50 times might be scripted like `printf %050d|tr 0 \\n`, But is this really a question about how to gen 50 blank lines? By the way - don't `export` functions - that's a nasty business.

Comment: lol yeah I have just added a function very similar to that to my `~/.bashrc` file and then `export` it from there so its just a quick command away.  I guess an alias would work too but that's the method I choose.  But good idea!!!

Comment: I've colored my prompt bright green and blue so I can tell where each command began. I find it's more clear than blank lines between commands.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you are trying to archive. Obviously you are trying to compare `dir1` with `dir2`. Are you searching for files that are in both directories or files that are missing?

Comment: Dylan, having the data in a file was meant to be the most flexible approach. I suggested that because it's not clear fro your question what you typically will do when browsing the listings. There are numerous other ways, depending on what you want to do; e.g. open two windows and compare that side by side, or use some "screen" program, or (I think) the "emacs" editor can do that, or you can directly compare data from the two "ls" commands using "diff" and "process substitution", piping the result through less, etc. You see?! (BTW, it's `less file`, without `cat`).

Answer (score 1):

Please take what it follows only as hints to stimulate to your fantasy.
You can set up your *bash function* or *alias* with one or more of the following ideas.

### Text B/W

As pointed out by mikeserv you can use  `printf %020d` to introduce a big skip before the output of ls.

```
alias Ls0='printf %050d|tr 0 \\n; ls -la'
```

Moreover you can custom it with some separations layer or messages...

```
alias Ls1='printf %020d|tr 0 \\n;echo "# Output of $(pwd)"; \
           printf %02d|tr 0 \\n;  ls -la'
```

### Text Coloured

In a more creative way you can use the colours and you will have the 1st line in green

```
alias Ls2='tput setaf 2; ls -la'
```

Even here you can enjoy in custom solutions; you can cycle among the first 3 colour of [`tput`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tput+1), have a 1st line with background inverted, coloured...

```
alias Ls3='ccol=$(echo "($ccol +1) %3+1" | bc); tput  setaf $ccol; ls -la'
alias Ls4='tput rev; ls -la'
alias Ls5='echo -e "setf 7\nsetb 1" | tput -S ; ls -la'
```

### Old Fashion Banner

Just in case you have installed a banner package you can think to something like:

```
alias Ls6='printf "\n\n"; banner $(basename $(pwd)) ; printf "\n\n"; ls -la'
alias Ls7='printf "\n\n"; tput setaf 2; banner $(basename $(pwd)); \
           printf "\n\n"; ls -la'
```

and start to use mixed solutions...

Notes:

1. If you put it in a function you can manage better the eventual parameters
   When `ls -la` is in the last position you can try to add other parameters at *"execution time"*.
2. [`man tput`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tput+1) and [`man terminfo`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?terminfo+5) for further curiosity
3. It's possible to use the escaping sequence too for colouring the output 
   `(echo -e '\E[31m' ; ls -la)`

Comment: This are all very interesting ideas... I think I am going to combine a couple of your ideas or better yet I think I might try to set it up so that my `PS1` is a certain color every time and then every time I issue a command the output of that command is different. So for example my first `ls` command will be green then my next `cd` command will be blue then my next `ls` command will be white and just cycle through the colors.  When I get home Ill try out your ideas and mine.  I will likely be accepting your answer. Already +1

Comment: If you have to do a visual comparison of 2 directories `mc`, the _GNU Midnight Commander_  can be cosy... BTW now I miss where I put it... but with a  couple of _for_ and some escape chars it's possible to do a bar with different tone of the same colours to centre it in screen just to separate the output of ls...